# Deployment of block chain in cloud

Tags: azure, cloud, corda

I have create cordapp in azure VM. now i want to deploy that cordapp into Azure cloud server so that client from anywhere can hit cordapp. but i confused whether i have to use webapps or inbuilt Blockchain module in marketplace. if so, how to do deploy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deploy a node to a cloud server by following the instructions here: https://docs.corda.net/deploying-a-node.html.

You can then interact with your node remotely, using either:

- An RPC client (e.g. https://github.com/corda/cordapp-template-java/blob/release-V3/clients/src/main/java/com/template/Client.java)
- A server (e.g. https://github.com/corda/cordapp-template-java/tree/release-V3/clients/src/main/java/com/template/webserver)
- The node shell over SSH (Corda V3 onwards - see https://docs.corda.net/head/shell.html#the-shell-via-ssh)

Comment: It's to help people quickly set up networks of Corda nodes on Azure. It is not required.

Comment: i checked https://docs.corda.net/deploying-a-node.html for deploying in windows server.i can see deploying nodes using NSSM Manager.
     1.when i deploy nodes, how it will access my application which is placed as a jar under /opt/corda /CordaApp.jar
     2. Also, When i run nssm.bat file under each nodes , my cmd is going on running with the first cmd and not stopping. Nothing proceed after that.

Comment: Could you raise these as separate questions please?